# SchemaLocation in JIBX generated xml

Tags: jibx

I am generating xml from Java object using JIBX. I want schemalocation to be set in generated xml. I am able to put namespace but but schemaLocation. Anyone has one idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this as an attribute value on the root element of your output document, along these lines:

```
<value name="schemaLocation" ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" field="locationField"/>
```